# Writing my own basic shell: Dealing with double quoted arguments

Tags: c, shell, double-quotes

I am working on a basic unix shell and I am proud to say that it is working awesome and I've learned so much throughout its development. There is one feature that I am missing, and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it work, perhaps my brain is just burnt out.

If I receive the following input:

echo "Hello World"

I need to parse the input so that double quoted arguments are considered one argument to the command, and not two separate arguments.

The way I am thinking of accomplishing this, is I need a way to detect if there are 2 quotations in the arguments. If we find them, we will need a separate parse function to deal with them.

I've included my parse function, as I assume this is where the magic needs to happen. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
//parse
char ** parse(char *input){
   char *token;
   char **args;
   args = malloc (MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char));
   int i = 1;
   token = strtok(input, " \n\t()<>|&;");
   args[0] = token; //this is the command

   token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t()<>|&;");
   while (token != NULL){
       args[i] = token; // these are the arguments
       i++;
       token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t()<>|&;");

   }
   args[i] = NULL; //end the array with NULL (required for execvp)
   return args;
}
```

Comment: I would offer that `strtok` is totally underpowered here; for example it does not deal with `foo "bar < baz"` correctly.

Comment: It is optional for our shell to properly deal with redirection, and piping. Mine doesn't :)

Comment: What I mean is, your `strtok` code above will be tokenizing based on the `<` **inside** a quoted string...

Comment: You need to find a delimiter (not using `strtok()` since it destroys the information you need — like what the delimiter character is), and if it is double quote, going into different parsing code because the rules for double-quoted strings are different.  You'll need to generate an error if the double quotes are not balanced. Eventually, you'll need to deal with backslashes and dollars (and maybe back-quotes) too.

Comment: What is `MAX_SIZE`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than embedding an ad-hoc lexer in your `parse` function, I would recommend either 1) generating one using `lex` or the like, or 2) hand-coding one. If you use a lexer-generator which is based on regular expressions, a double-quoted string can be lexed as a single token using a rule like `"[^"]*"`. If you want to be able to use backslashes to escape a double quote, you could use a rule like `"(\.|[^\"])*"`.